# Bits, bytes, character, and integer sizes in C

Tags: c, byte, bit, primitive

From what I've googled and found on stackoverflow, I've seen that a character is always 1 byte. This is for sure. But, I've also seen that it may not be 8 bits (it could be greater, see CHAR_BITS). Does this mean that if it is, lets say, 10 bits, in some hypothetical architecture, then 1 byte = 10 bits? Does this imply that if the implementation defaults integers to 4 bytes, then the size of an int will be 40 bits? I'm a little wonky with all this bit-byte variation, despite the insane number of threads on the internet.

Comment: Why is it important to know if a "byte"/`char` is 8,9,16, etc. bits?  Usually that answer to that question points out that bit width is not important, but the _type_ is.  If code needs 8-bits, use `(u)int8_t`. If code needs 32-bits, use `(u)int32_t`, If code needs at least 32-bits, use `(u)int_least32_t.` or `long`, etc.  If code needs to know the range of `int`, use `INT_MIN/INT_MAX`.

Comment: Less of a question of "why is it important", more of a question of truly understanding literally everything before I move on, which my OCD prevents me from doing. But yes, I understand why I can simply use those typedefs. From what I understand right now, is that the C standard treats a "byte" as something the size of a character. Now conventionally, this might be 8 bits, but it could also be more. Regardless, C counts this size as a byte, for the sake of terminology, whereas normally we define a byte as 8 bits. Hopefully I've got it.

Comment: BITD, C pioneered a middle ground amongst the wide variety of architectures. Taking one company's normal "byte" and another platform's different size "byte" into "byte"/`char` is at least 8 bits, platform dependent  and is the smallest unit. That innovation beget portable code that adhered to that loose definition.Today there is an ever tightening of market acceptable architectures.  If one wants very tight coding definitions, C is not the best choice. If one wants a language that is adaptable to innovation and yet not foregoing the past, C - warts (many) and all - is a long term good choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For modern platforms these sizes are predictable, byte is eight bits, int is four or eight bytes, and so on. The definition and implementation of "bytes" is unlikely to change as this version of it coalesced around the introduction of 8-bit CPUs in the 1970s which arguably lead to the triumph of ASCII over competing standards. It has become so ingrained that some languages treat it literally: in French the word for "byte" is "octet".

For historical platforms all bets are off. Some use 10, 12, 18 or 36 bit integers. Early computers didn't use bytes at all but instead [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) which are of arbitrary size. Things are comprised of these units, where a "double word" value might be 48 bits for whatever reason. This is from an era when a single bit might be represented by several vacuum tubes or full-sized transistors so practical cost concerns lead to some very *unusual* designs.

Now when it comes to characters, they are not necesarily one byte. In [UNICODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) they can be a lot more than that, especially when expressed as UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32, the common encoding methods for this sort of text. It is only in 8-bit encodings like Latin1 that characters and bytes are interchangeable.

It's important to consider that while most consumer CPUs are pretty homogeneous in their sizes, this all goes out the window when dealing with specialized devices like DSPs or custom FPGA processors.

The good news is that you're unlikely to do character processing on a DSP or custom FPGA processor that's built around unusual register sizes. Those are usually focused on processing some other kind of digital data.

Comment: ASCII is 7-bits. Some of the first C computers had 9-bit "bytes" because the word size 36 couldn't be divided evenly by 7, but 9 would do. I guess there was no single architecture with actual 7-bit addressable bytes for which C would be supported.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're right about ASCII being a 7-bit standard, but it's generally been stored in 8 bits where the upper 128 characters are left to the vendor for various purposes, often used for graphical characters or accented letter variants. I mean ASCII, and by extension the 8-bit "ANSI" set popularized by the IBM PC, as opposed to EBCDIC or the other attempts at creating character standards.